# Which is the best way to get object class' short name?

Tags: php

I know these tricks:

```
 $short_class_name1 = strrev(explode('\\', strrev(get_class($obj)), 2)[0]);

 $short_class_name2 = substr($f = get_class($obj), -strpos(strrev($f), '\\'));

 $short_class_name3 = (new \ReflectionClass($obj))->getShortName();
```

All of them give the same result, but which is better to use? Will I get some performance benefit from using first two of them?

Comment: I think you should look into the `use` keyword (might not be applicable - but worth a look)

Comment: Did you mean to use the `$f` in `strrev` in the second version?

Comment: ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, it's not for my purposes. Aurel Bílý , yes, thanks.

Comment: There is no "better", this is a question of opinion. About the performance: why don't you simply test it?

Comment: @Audiophile You lost me - what's not for your purposes? You can use to shorthand the class to do new class and then just use it :) then you don't have to declare vars at all other than just use `->objParam`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Could you provide an example? Of how I can use 'use' keyword to get a string with given object's short class name.